# Invertible Matrix and Linearly Independent Vectors Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to do this one:

Suppose $A$ is an invertible $n$ x $n$ matrix and the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_n$ are linearly independent.  Show that the vectors $Av_1$, $Av_2$, ..., $Av_n$ are linearly independent.

I know that A's column vectors are linearly independent since A is invertible.  I also know there is no relation amongst the $v_i$ because they're linearly independent.

My idea is to write the product of A and a given $v_i$ in terms of the columns of A.  Not sure if this is right, any guidance much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Maybe you can do a proof by contradiction? If they are lin dependent, then the zero vector can be written as a lin combination (with nonzero scalars) of your $Av's$ That means that a particular $Av$ vector can be written as a lin combination of the remaining $Av's$. Now what does that mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $w_i=Av_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. To show linear independence, we must show that 
$$ c_1w_1+\cdots+c_nw_n=0 \Longrightarrow c_i=0,\quad i=1,\dots n.$$
Since $A$ is invertible, we can left-multiply $c_1w_1+\dots=0$ by $A^{-1}$ to get...

Can you take it from there? Remember that the vectors $v_1,\dots v_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Ah this makes sense to me, thanks!

Comment: To finish it: We multiply on the left by $A^-1$ and get $c_1 v_1$ + ... + $c1 v_n$ = 0.  Since $v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent, we must have $c_i$ = 0 for all i.  Yes?

Comment: That's right, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that since $A$ is invertible then
$$Ax=0\iff x=0$$
Now let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in \Bbb R$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k Av_k=0\iff A\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k v_k\right)=0\iff \sum_{k=1}^na_k v_k=0\Rightarrow a_i=0\;\forall i$$
since $v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_n$ are linearly independent. Conclude.

Comment: Whoa! You've been busy with answers!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the definition directly? Justify/explain the following:

$$\text{For scalars}\;\;c_1,...,c_n\;:\;\;0=\sum_{k=1}^nc_kAv_k=\sum_{k=1}^nA(c_kv_k)=A\left(\sum_{k=1}^nc_kv_k\right)\iff$$

$$\iff\sum_{k=1}^nc_kv_k=0\iff c_1=c_2=\ldots=c_n=0$$